# Answer Set Programming Beginner

Tags: clingo

I am a beginner in Answer Set Programming and completely new to clingo. I tried the facts and constraints below on nurses shift on clingo, but I am not getting any model and clingo not flagging any error. I keep getting UNSAT. What am I not doing right?

```
nurselimits(x, min, max). 
worklimits(min, max).
daylimits(x, t, min, max).
x(morning; afternoon; night; off; leave).
x(1..5).


day(1..28).
days(28).
nurse(1..40).
shift(1, morning, 8).
shift(2, afternoon, 14).
shift(3, night, 20).
shift(4, off, 0).
shift(5, leave, 10).
nurselimits(1,6,9).
nurselimits(2,6,9).
nurselimits(3,4,7).
daylimits(1,8,6,9).
daylimits(2,8,6,9).
daylimits(3,8,5,10).
worklimits(132,228).



 {assign(N, X, D) : shift(X, Name, H), X != 4, X != 5} = 1:- nurse(N), day(D).



:- day(D), #count{N : assign(N, X, D)} > max, nurselimits(x, min, max).
:- day(D), #count{N : assign(N, X, D)} < min, nurselimits(x, min, max).

:- nurse(N), #sum{H, D : assign(N, X, D), shift(X, Name, H)} > max, worklimits(min, max).
:- nurse(N), #sum{H, D : assign(N, X, D), shift(X, Name, H)} < min, worklimits(min, max).


:- nurse(N), assign(N, X1, D), assign(N, X2, D+1), X2 < X1 , X1 <= 3.

:- nurse(N), day(D), days(DAYS), D <= DAYS-21, 
   #count{D1 : assign(N, 4, D1), D1 >= D, D1 <= D+21} = 1.


:- nurse(N), #count{D: assign(N, X, D)} > max, daylimits(x, t, min, max).

:- nurse(N), #count{D: assign(N, X, D)} < min, daylimits(x, t, min, max).
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that actually describes a problem or asks a question. It should be clear and descriptive enough to be of use to a future user of this site who is scanning through a list of search results looking for a problem solution. Your current title provides nothing meaningful that will help that user. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
nurselimits(x, min, max). 
worklimits(min, max).
daylimits(x, t, min, max).
x(morning; afternoon; night; off; leave).
x(1..5).
```

There are several problems. The symbols `x`, `min`, `max`, `t`. Are all non-numerical symbolic constants, much like `morning`, `afternoon`,etc. That is probably unintended, unless you are substituting them using the `-c` command line option. Certainly, the `x` in `nurselimits` has nothing to do with the `x(1..5)` in your code, which also seems unintended. Also, the constant `min` is the same symbolic value in  `nurselimits`, `worklimits` and `daylimits`. Perhaps you wanted it to be variable instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove first three lines and add #show (e.g. #show assign/3.) of any predicate you want to see in the answer sets.